# how should I think in object or how to make the most out of objects?

Tags: oop

I know the concept of OOP for couple of years and I'm aware of using it and creating lets say not too complicated objects.

but I want to understand the OOP way better than the place I am stand right now and use it just like a real pro.

actually  I'm an independent programmer I have to deal with several languages and platforms like php/.net/c++/QT and sometimes I feel lost between these giant stuff and I'm away from the OOP concept.

-is there any approach to overcome this problem ?

-I want to know how to think in a fully OOP way and creating a business object as well as business plan as fast as possible then use it in my favorite language.

-is there any relation between knowing an language very well and then learning OOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have learned the concepts, the best way to better understand it would be to use it in practice. Use OOP concepts to help you accomplish what you need to.

You seem to be inferring that with OOP you are asking yourself "Am I doing it right?"
A good place to start would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

The best way to think OOP and creating business objects is to go with what the business says something is.

For example, let's assume your business has 2 different types of customers: Online and Local.

Perhaps you would then create a base Class Customer and create 2 other Classes OnlineCustomer and LocalCustomer which Inherit from the base Class Customer. This will allow you to add things specific to each customer Class which are not pertinent to the other. For example, you would probably want an email address for OnlineCustomer while you may want a standard mailing address for LocalCustomer (*obviously nowadays everybody wants email addresses from everybody if they can get them but this was the best example I could come up with off the top of my head :)* ).

As for any specific relation to learning a language or knowing it versus learning concepts, I would assume it would be easier to implement and use a new programming concept such as OOP after knowing the basics of a language.

Answer (score 1):

Learn (at least) one pure object-oriented language and use it for some time. It will force you to use OO and over time you will start to think in matter of classes, objects and methods.

Comment: Most developers today are doing procedural programming in an object oriented language. The language will not force you to do anything OO.  If you look at most code today, you will see an almost flat inheritance structure with very little code re-use.  In fact, the best way to learn object oriented thinking is to study the UML and design patterns.  You will come away with knowledge applicable to any OO language.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in procedural programming, and OO is not essential for code reuse (any programming paradigm with callable code blocks allows for code reuse). On the other hand, neither do design patterns require OO approach, although it maps fairly well.

Comment: Wow!  Really?  I find your comments amusing since OO itself was created specifically to answer the shortcomings of procedural programming.  Design patterns are native to object orientation.  You will not see references to functions and structures in design patterns because these are procedural constructs, you will see references to classes, methods, instances and responsibilities.  If all you have are functions, and that is all you have in procedural programming, what kind of patterns do you imagine one could construct other than function calls function?